# Difference of two random variable distributions

Tags: python, cumulative-distribution-function, convolution

I have two sets of random variables. I have generated two CDFs for them. Two of the CDFs are plotted graphically.[image] I need to find the difference in distribution of the two CDFs. 
I have learned about the method called convolution of distributions, which gives the distribution of the sums. If we add the negation of one distribution to be subtracted, we get the difference of distribution (like, A - B = A + (-B) ) which is what I needed.

Could anyone suggest me some software tools like scipy in python, which I can use for finding a solution to my problem?

Comment: In what form are your CDFs represented?  As functions, as empirical CDFs (which essentially are lists of data), as PDFs to be integrated, as characteristic functions, cumulant functions, or something else?

Comment: I have the list of values of random variables and the corresponding CDFs are represented as list of values.

Answer (score 5):

Are the two random variables $X$ and $Y$ supposed to be independent? If so, it is easy to prove that the distribution function of $Z=X-Y$ is given by the convolution
$$
  F_Z(z) = P(X-Y\leq z) = \int F_X(z+y) \, dF_Y(y) \, .
$$
Hence, one idea is to compute the empirical distribution functions $\hat{F}_m$ of $(x_1,\dots,x_m)$, and $\hat{G}_n$ of $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$, and use
$$
  \hat{H}(z) = \int \hat{F}_m(z+y)\,d\hat{G}_n(y) = \frac{1}{m\,n}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m I_{[x_j,\infty)}(z + y_i)
$$
as an estimate for $F_Z(z)$. Note that the corresponding estimator is strongly consistent for each $z$.

Comment: That's correct (+1) and it's a substantial improvement over the other answer proposing a Monte-Carlo evaluation of the right hand side  of your formula.  However, I believe $\hat{H}$ can be computed reasonably accurately by means of the FFT in $O((m+n)\log(m+n))$ effort compared to the $O(mn)$ effort implied by the double summation.

Comment: That's a huge saving, Bill! Can you post a few tips on how to do it? Tks.

Comment: One method either approximates the PDFs as histograms with constant-width bins or computes a kernel density estimate (that is, it *rasterizes* the PDFs in one dimension) and applies the FFT directly to obtain the PDF of the convolution and finally accumulates that to create the CDF. Although there are some obvious shortcomings in some cases (e.g., extreme outliers can be wasteful), this method looks appealing for any medium to large datasets. The technique I just described is used routinely in two and three dimensions for spatial analysis.

Comment: Could you tell us what $f_Z(z)$ would be if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a special package to do this; ordinary [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) is enough.  I've appended example code and its output below.  Note that the cdf of (A-B) looks very similar to the cdfs of A and B separately, but actually it's not.  You can see a subtle difference at around +/- 2 or 3 sigma.  The cdf of (A-B) is a little wider than the individual cdfs of A and B separately.

[image: Example cdf of difference of two Gaussian pdfs]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#!/usr/bin/env python

# Number of random draws to use
ndraws = 1000
# Set this distance (in sigmas) large enough to capture all of the outliers
plotrange = 5
# Number of bins to use for pdf/cdf
nbin = 100
# Get random draws from a Gaussian
A = np.random.randn(1,ndraws)
B = np.random.randn(1,ndraws)
dfAB = A - B

# Calculate cdfs of A and B
Apdf, edges = np.histogram(A, bins=nbin, range=(-plotrange, plotrange))
Bpdf, edges = np.histogram(B, bins=nbin, range=(-plotrange, plotrange))
dfABpdf, edges = np.histogram(dfAB, bins=nbin, range=(-plotrange, plotrange))
xrng = (edges[0:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2

Acdf = np.cumsum(map(float, Apdf)) / ndraws
Bcdf = np.cumsum(map(float, Bpdf)) / ndraws
dfABcdf = np.cumsum(map(float,dfABpdf)) / ndraws

# Plot cdfs and differences of cdfs
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.plot(xrng, Acdf)
ax1.set_title("A cdf")

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.plot(xrng, Bcdf)
ax2.set_title("B cdf")

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.plot(xrng, dfABcdf)
ax3.set_title("(A-B) cdf")

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax4.plot(xrng, Acdf - Bcdf)
ax4.set_title("(A cdf) - (B cdf)")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Is this lumpy or numpy?

Comment: It's numpy, with an "n".  It's a dependency for scipy, which the original poster explicitly mentioned in the question, so I would have assumed he/she would have already known about it. BTW, if you are using numpy/scipy, I would recommend working in Python 2.7.x rather than Python 3.x, as numpy/scipy is not yet well-supported in Python 3.x.  Numpy and scipy are not a part of the standard Python library, however, if you just want to try it out, [this distribution](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) of Python 2.7.x installs easily and has a copy of numpy/scipy already bundled together.

Comment: What does this code do? If I read it correctly, it appears to amount to (a) assuming the two datasets are exactly the same size and (b) randomly permuting one of them, pairing its values with the other, and computing the differences. If that's the case, then this solution would be extremely limited and very inefficient, so perhaps I'm missing some Python subtlety.  Your explanation of how it's supposed to work would be welcome.

Comment: @whuber: yes, you read correctly. My understanding was that the author just wanted a simple demo of how to calculate--in Python, specifically--the cdf of the difference of two random variables. I provided that, in the plot at the lower left. In addition, to cover my bases in case I had misunderstood the question, I also plotted the difference of the cdfs of two random variables, at lower right. Assumption of equal sample size is not a huge limitation; you can always throw away data, or do bootstrap resampling to achieve something approximately similar. As for efficiency, code runs in < 1 sec.

Comment: "Efficiency" does not refer to computing time, but rather to use of the information available.  This approach achieves a very imprecise estimate of the difference compared to what can be attained with the information.

Comment: @stachyra The CDF data contains the random variables arranged in the ascending order. So values of both the random variables are arranged in ascending order and hence looses mutual order correspondence among each other. 
As far as I understood, the code line "dfAB = A - B" just finds the difference of ordered sample. Can we find the difference preserving their mutual order and finding their difference?

Comment: @whuber: in my very simple example as I've defined it, information is cheap; if you want more, just increase the number of draws. In a more realistic example with limited and unequal sample sizes for A and B, I suppose an alternative more general approach would be to define the "differences" pdf as $p(x=(A-B)) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}p_{A}(a)\delta(x-(a-b))p_{B}(b) da db$ (where $\delta$ represents a Dirac delta), calculate it numerically, and then cumsum to get cdf. The Python code would be a bit more complicated though; I wanted to show a simpler example first.

Comment: @Steffie: at the code line "dfAB = A - B", the values of A and B are not yet ordered. The ordering happens, effectively, with the call to np.histogram(). (Technically, the ordering is only approximate in a histogram, as values which are nearby one another are all grouped together into a single bin.) The code example I gave preserves the random mutual order at the point in the code execution sequence where the difference is actually calculated.

Comment: There are rapidly diminishing returns with the randomized approach.  You will get more accuracy per unit computational effort with a direct calculation of the result.  Achieving this would be important with long-tailed distributions where it can take a very large number of draws to obtain the tails of the convolution.